# Creating an indefinite amount of items

Tags: java, methods, queue, deque

What is wrong with my code?  Specifically the array of object item `item2[count]`   Originaly I was trying to insert `item1` into the queue but encountered a problem where the previous values of the object Item stored in the que were over written by the newly inserted ones.  My solution was to declare an array of objects `item2[count]` and increment `int count` and now I am getting exceptions for `insertFront` `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0` and `insertRear` `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`

Main:

```
public class MyDequeApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //variables
        String userinNum;
        double userinPrice;
        int queOp=0;

        //???
        int count=0;

        //creating new Item
        Item item1 = new Item();
        //array of items!!!????
        Item[] item2=new Item[count];

        //creating new Scanner      
        Scanner scan1=new Scanner(System.in);

        //user input number of elements in the deque
        System.out.println("Enter the number of elements in the que");
        int queElm=scan1.nextInt();     
        MyDeque theQueue=new MyDeque(queElm);
        //MyDeque theStack=new MyDeque(queElm);

        //do/while so while user selects 1-7 they stay in the switch/case
        do {
            //switch/case menu
            System.out.println("1. Insert to front");
            System.out.println("2. Insert to rear");
            System.out.println("3. Remove from front");
            System.out.println("4. Remove from rear");
            System.out.println("5. Peek front");
            System.out.println("6. Peek rear");
            System.out.println("7. Display deque");
            System.out.println("Anything else to Quit");

            //user input the case number
            queOp=scan1.nextInt();
            scan1.nextLine();

            //for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {  //for start
                switch(queOp) {     
                    //insert to front
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("Enter an item number");
                        userinNum=scan1.nextLine();
                        item1.setNum(userinNum);
                        System.out.println("Enter a price");
                        userinPrice=scan1.nextDouble();
                        scan1.nextLine();
                        item1.setPrice(userinPrice);
                        System.out.println(item1.toString());
                        item2[count]=item1;
                        theQueue.insertFront(item2[count]);
                        count++;
                        break;                  
                    //insert to rear
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("Enter an item numbeR");
                        userinNum=scan1.nextLine();
                        item1.setNum(userinNum);
                        System.out.println("Enter a pricE");
                        userinPrice=scan1.nextDouble();
                        scan1.nextLine();
                        item1.setPrice(userinPrice);
                        System.out.println(item1.toString());
                        //item2[count]=item1;
                        theQueue.insertRear(item2[count]);
                        count++;
                        break;
                }
          //}
        }
    }
}
```

Methods from class `MyDeque`

```
public class MyDeque {

    private int maxSize;
    private Item[] queArray;
    private int front;
    private int rear;
    private int nItems;

    //constructor
    public MyDeque(int s) {
        maxSize = s;
        queArray = new Item[maxSize];
        front = 0;
        rear = -1;
        nItems = 0;
    }

    //insertFront()
    //For an insertion operation, you have to prompt the user to type in the item#
    //and the price. Create an object of the Item and then pass the object as the
    //argument to the insertion method
    public void insertFront(Item x) {
        if(front==maxSize)
        front=0;
        queArray[front++]=x;
        nItems++;
    }

    //insertRear()
    public void insertRear(Item y) {
        if(rear==maxSize-1) //wraparound
            rear=-1;
        queArray[++rear]=y; //CHANGED TO ++rear increment rear and insert
        nItems++;   //one more item
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is simple.

When you are looping to get input from the user to insert another Item into the queue or array, you need to create a new Item object:

```
Item newItem = new Item();
```

If you don't create a new Item, then you are just changing the values on an existing item in the queue, effectively overwriting their values.

You don't need the array either.

Based on our possible inputs, the logic should look something like:
queueOp is an int, so you should be calling `scan1.nextInt()`

```
Get queueOp from user
switch(queueOp)
 case 1:
    create new Item and set values (`new Item()`)
    call method insertFront(pass new Item)
 case 2: 
    create new Item and set values
    call method insertRear(pass new Item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your item2 array is initialized with length 0:

```
int count=0;
...
Item[] item2=new Item[count];
```

An never is allocated new. So your call iitem2[count]=item1 will fail, because you are accessing the first element of an array whose length is zero (i.e. it has no elements!).

Consider to use a List which will grow at each call to add( item).

**But**: Why do you want to store it there? Your task is to store it theQueue, isn't it?

Comment: if i keep on inserting item1 to the queue it over writes previously inserted items.  I thought if i stored them from an array i could keep the newest value form over writing the previous ones

Comment: Yes, see pczeus' answer!